# Creating PDF from HTML facing a few issues

Tags: php, pdf, imagick, html2pdf

I am creating PDF using PHP imagick, passing HTML to PHP and generating PDF.
But font is not looking fine and facing some issues in PDF.

Difference image is here:

[image]

HTML and PDF files are in Google drive:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9IYq9nFFmOkZ245LVZkZ2xjNUU

**UPDATE**:

I am using imagick module version 3.4.1. It was a spelling mistake. command I have:

```
$orientation = 'Landscape'; exec('wkhtmltopdf --lowquality --page-height 200 --page-width 155 -B 3 -L 3 -R 3 -T 6 --page-offset -1 --orientation '.$orientation.' '.' /directory/PDF/'.$_POST['uid'].'.html'.' /directory/'.$name);
```

Comment: What is your exact Imagemagick command line? Are you using PHP exec() with Imagemagick or Imagick? What version of Imagemagick and what version of Imagick, if using it. Are you calling the HTML file from the Internet via http or downloading the source and trying to convert that?

Comment: @fmw42: I am using imagick module version 3.4.1. 
It was spelling mistake. 
command i have,  
$orientation = 'Landscape';
exec('wkhtmltopdf --lowquality --page-height 200 --page-width 155 -B 3 -L 3 -R 3 -T 6 --page-offset -1 --orientation '.$orientation.' '.' /directory/PDF/'.$_POST['uid'].'.html'.' /directory/'.$name);

Comment: I think wkhtmltopdf is using different font or thicker one, check your CSS maybe you can specify the break-word or check if the wkhtmltopdf has (support) the font you are using or specified in CSS

Comment: DiarSelimi / fmw42 please up vote my question, there is nothing wrong in my question